# How to use Vue to call API when the focus leaves the input box?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

my just encountered difficulties when learning `vue,` and I don't know how to implement it. I hope someone can help me!

First, I declare that my English is not good, but I try to express my problem completely.

The current project hopes to call the API after leaving the input box after entering the content in the input box, but I will only delay him by 0.4 seconds. I don't know how to change the code to call the API when I leave the input box. I found an onBlur event on the Internet, but I still don't know how to write it, because I am really new to `vue`. I hope I can get your help. thank you.

[This is my program project](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/qBmRbpy?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to replace the `@input` event with `@blur`

```
<el-input v-model="inputData" placeholder="Content" @blur="delayFetch" />
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/DannyFeliz/pen/wvdgGBo?editors=1010)